# got a little fuzzy about the linkedlist in java

Tags: java

say, I want to create a array, with which elements are linkedlists. firstly I create a Node class then I create Linkedlist class. Also, I write a "addLast" method in Linkedlist class, which function is to add one node to the tail of linkedlist. then I define a array Linkedlist[] list = new Linkedlist[2];

Now the problem happens: since the elements in "list" array are all linkedlists, I instantiated a node to Node class and if I want to use "addLast" method to add one node at list[0], which is: list[0].addLast(node);

It does not work.

Really got fuzzy and headache, could anybody help me please?

Comment: Did you actually put any lists in your array, or is it still full of nulls?

Comment: Also, "It does not work" is way too vague. What actually happens? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Your list[0] might be null.

Comment: No, originally, the array of linkedlists are full of nulls, then I want to add the first nodes at array[0], which is the head of a linkedlist.

Comment: When debugging, the debugger says: "Source not found".

Comment: Yes, the list[0] is null, and I want to add the first node to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After** you define the array with:

```
Linkedlist[] list = new Linkedlist[2]
```

And **before** adding a node to a list in the array with:

```
list[0].addLast(node);
```

You must instantiate the list you wish to add the node to:

```
list[0] = new LinkedList();
```

Comment: Thank you, Eran!!!! Problem solved!!! But could you tell me reason why I should do this? I am new to Java, get a little fuzzy about it.

Comment: @HaolinZhang When you create an array of a reference type (i.e. an array of Object or a sub-class of Object), all the elements of the array are initialized to null. In order to do something with the i'th element of the array, you must first assign an object to it. Otherwise, list[i].doSomething would throw NullPointerException.

Comment: By the way, there is another similar problem, say that I create a class Item, with two member variables: name and score; and two member methods: getName and getScore. Then I create another class List, which has one member variable: table (which is array of Item), and three member methods: printList, addItem and Instantiation (which is used to solve the problem below). Here the problem comes: In printItem method, I want to print all the Items in List if the Item is not null. I use the judge sentence:if(list.table[i].getName().equals(null)).

Comment: It does not looks good even though I already have instantiated all the Item' name and score to null before I adding Items to the list.

Comment: It looks like whenever there is a element which is not "blank" element, which means the name and score are not null, the judge sentence will not work, and here jumps an exception:java.lang.NullPointerException